# Terrible FPS in simple game

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

So I'm making a simple 2d game where the player moves on the x axis and picks up falling objects. I have a script to spawn the objects above the player, here it is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] locationsToSpawn;
    private float counter = 0;
    [SerializeField]
    string[] listOfPossibleTags;
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject[] objectToSpawn;
    [SerializeField]
    float timeBetweenSpawns = 3.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        locationsToSpawn = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("SpawnLocation");
    }
    void Update()
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        if (counter > timeBetweenSpawns)
        {
            GameObject spawnedObject;
            spawnedObject = Instantiate(objectToSpawn[Random.Range(0,objectToSpawn.Length)], locationsToSpawn[Random.Range(0, locationsToSpawn.Length)].transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            spawnedObject.gameObject.tag = listOfPossibleTags[Random.Range(0, listOfPossibleTags.Length)];
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

However, after picking up just a few objects the game becomes so laggy and eventually crashes Unity! I have Intel i7, 8GB RAM, Nvidia 550m so my laptop probably isn't an issue. Also worth mentioning that my point counter goes crazy with my spawned objects, but counts objects I place manually perfectly (in other words, the spawned objects make my points counter count way too many points). Any ideas on why my game is causing low FPS? Thanks!

Comment: can you add your "picking up" script here?

Comment: BTW, instead of setting `counter` to zero, you should set `counter -= timeBetweenSpawns`. This eliminates remainder error, and you want to get into a habit of writing it this way. It becomes more important as you deal with faster events, like those that happen once every few frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems like you are Instantiating a lot of gameobjects in "Update" at runtime and not destroying them. Ideally what you should be doing is Instantiating required gameobjects once only, store it in the objectpool and reusing it at runtime. There are lots of example available to do this, you just need to google.

Answer (score 1):

Use profiler to test your game and look for the spikes inside your game. This will help you identify easily that which part of your code is creating problems as it is not necessary that your object spawn script is causing problems.

In one of my projects I faced a problem where my font was causing FPS drop.

As you mentioned your "points counter" then I would ask if you are using custom font? If yes then is it set to dynamic? If yes then this might be the issue as Unity renders the dynamic font at runtime and every time you update the text and so it is suggested to use dynamic font for static menus but not for constantly changing text.

For more detail on profilers Look at the following links:

1. [Introduction to Profiler - Unity Official Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBpXiJ9G3OY)
2. [Unity Manual - Profiler](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html)
3. [Unity Manual - Profiler Window](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerWindow.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you releasing the "picked up" items from memory? As you create each one it uses memory to handle location, movement, etc. If you don't release that memory then eventually you run out of it.

I have only watched videos of Unity but never coded in it, so I can't explain how to release the memory but I know that with all computer programs, memory must be released. So languages and software auto releases memory...others have to be done manually.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, all games will be laggy cause of the instantiate method. If you need to use it then use it in `void Start() {...}` or `void Awake() {...}` and cache all created objects. With these cached objects create a object pooling and save performance.

Dont use transform from Unitys created instance, make sure you create a cached object

```
private Transform _transform;
void Start() {
    _transform = transform;
}
```

Instead of doing your own calculating `counter > timebetweenSpawn` make sure you use [InvokeRepeating](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) to save performance.

Make sure created objects in editor (if not moving objects) are **static**. You do not have to redraw them if the are not to be moved.

Unity [Profiler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBpXiJ9G3OY) will be your best friend. Benchmark everything.

Dont make change on Scale on a `Transform` object, better to change the size of image you are using. Scale takes performance.

*FixedUpdate = physics*

*Update = game logics*

Keep an eye out for **Tris** and **Verts**, you want to keep them as low as possible.